# Finding the first index of the longest repeating sequence

Tags: java, arrays, computer-science

```
public static int[] first = { 3391, 3391, 3391, 0, -1036, -3676, -4840,
        3798, 0, 0, -1350, -1350, 4320, -265, -265, 3222, 3222, -77, 0, 0,
        -3344, -3018, 1479, -2085, -2085, -2085, -2085, -2085, 0, 3205,
        -3775, 1165, 1165, 0, 0, 747, -1584, -3320, 3301, 0, -194, 1595,
        1595, 0, 440, 722, 722, 722, 722, 3130, -2978, 4215, 4215, 4215,
        766, 766, -157, -3206, 0, 0, -2630, 3348, 3348, 0, 0, -3942, -1545,
        326, 326, 4901, -4048, 0, -1388, -1388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4604, -2998, 0,
        -963, 0, 2555, -3578, 875, 410, 410, 2610, -4244, -4244, -4244,
        3474, 4073, -3865, -1618, -467, 4630, -2874, -2874, 1660, 1660,
        4236, 4236, 0, -1532, 2544, -1869, -1869, 0, -4064, 3383, -1648,
        -4642, -4090, -4090, -4090, 1611, -587, 0, 0, 0, 551, 551, 551,
        551, 0, 1418, 2953, 3892, -547, -547, 1847, 1719, -3701, 2335,
        3193, -4723, -3818, -3818, 1140, 1140, 4154, 3947, 0, 0, -2992,
        -2992, 4351, 4351, 213, 213, 213, -2177, 3029, 1275, -1086, -4651,
        -4651, 3380, 669, -3962, -3962, -3962, 0, 0, 0, 1764, 496, -4707,
        1554, 4758, 0, 280, 3979, -4812, 1678, 43, -979, -2610, 725, 725,
        4653, -2571, -2571, -4435, -4799, 4383, -2089, -2089, -2089, -2089,
        -2089, 4735, -3959, 3860, -3702, 2334, -3329, -3329, -3329, 3786,
        3786, -2057, 4172, 4172, -787, 31, 31, 1702, 3410, 3410, 2216,
        -1739, 770, 770, -861, 2107, 2107, -2089, 2432, 2432, 2543, 3422,
        2728, 2728, -1292, 3601, 0, 0, 1218, -1979, -2632, -2632, -214,
        -214, 0, -770, 4007, -4358, -1776, -867, -3334, -4020, 997, 3607,
        -794, 3828, 1740, 0, -38, -38, 870, 870, 870, 1691, 0, -3390, -290,
        -290, 4400, -2152, -1433, -1433, -265, -265, -4259, -2589, 4895,
        735, 735, 3246, -3913, -4163, -4163, 2084, -4086, -4086, 4486,
        2632, 2614, 3069, -3298, -4401, -4881, 2646, 2646, -1323, 4204, 0,
        0, -4828, 2662, 470, -3909, -3909, -787, -3675, -3675, -3861,
        -3861, 0, 0, -3093, -1750, -59, -3406, -1558, 2399, 4791, 2491,
        1287, 1287, 0, -3019, -1008, 0, 797, 1185, -439, -439, 0, 2470,
        3553, -4848, 2519, -3162, -2911, -2556, 2229, 1412, 0, 0, -350, 0,
        0, -3403, -3403, 3270, 3270, 2898, 2898, 2898, -1620, 2507, 1180,
        1180, 384, -4952, 2221, 3447, 3447, 3447, 3447, 1725, -2329, -2329,
        -902, 4760, 1092, 1092, 0, 420, 4324, 2048, 99, -3813, -1376,
        -1376, -1376, -1376, 564, 3107, -852, 3953, 0, -364, 3388, -2440,
        -2440, 1077, 0, 4340, -2646, 4644, -266, -409, 492, -3000, 1073,
        -1851, 1950, 1950, -1583, 4937, 3840, 3840, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2505,
        -1990, 1159, 1797, 0, 0, -146, 4521, -1095, -2776, 0, 2606, -3931,
        -3931, -3931, 2557, 2557, 2557, 2579, 1438, -980, 498, 0, -3139,
        4407, 4407, -9, 2287, 1633, -3942, -3942, -872, 2193, 0, 3894,
        -1069, -1069, -3094, 3376, 3376, 0, 0, -3017, -3017, -4278, -445,
        -4408, 2724, 0, 2678, 2398, -1388, 4676, 2958, 2958, 971, 3491,
        3491, 3793, 531, 0, -1278, -3552, -4599, -3125, 2763, -2599, 4505,
        -2964, -2964, 0, -1208, 0, 0, 3727, 3727, 0, 0, -562, 0, 1377,
        -239, -2957, -4129, -4129, -4129, -3265, 3275, -4140, -4140, -4140,
        2421, 2421, 2421, -1462, 1507, 1507, 1507, -4975, 2055, 341, 341,
        -2183, -2183, -2183, 348, -2964, -2964, 967, 3650, 3650, 0, 545, 0,
        -3443, 3970, -1816, 4905, 4905, -621, -621, -2103, 33, 1260, 1260,
        -3546, -3546, -922, -3519, 0, 0, 2382, 3425, -3021, -922, 4183,
        989, -1425, -1425, 0, 0, 0, 1784, 1784, 1784, 841, -616, -616,
        4488, 3820, 3820, 3820, 3768, 1050, -680, 3757, 2482, -2635, 1408,
        1408, -3100, -4242, -4242, -50, -50, -2013, -2013, -2013, -484,
        -4434, -4434, -4434, 1562, 1562, 1100, -763, -2597, 3203, 3203,
        3203, 2512, 2512, -1100, -1100, -1100, -1100, -1100, -1100, -3462,
        -3859, -1716, 4833, -1843, -1843, 421, 867, 4661, 566, 566, 2885,
        2885, 2176, -639, 4285, 4285, 4285, 3229, 3229, 0, 0, -3298, -3298,
        0, -1452, -3456, -1922, -1370, 4485, 4485, 422, 422, 322, 2044,
        3156, 1588, -2406, -2406, -2406, 2136, 4283, 2991, -969, 0, 0,
        -369, -369, 0, 4202, 85, 85, 41, -1917, -1917, -773, -3183, 1245,
        -1991, 2160, -2860, -2480, 2657, 2657, 2657, 2657, 4975, 760, 2750,
        -3876, 3738, 1255, -3385, -1946, 0, -1511, -4376, -3181, -3830,
        1862, 1862, -3265, -3265, -3265, 3379, 956, 4833, 4833, -969, 911,
        421, 421, -4156, 4045, 2478, -4151, -2899, -2721, -2721, -2721,
        -2399, -4976, 2447, 2447, 3534, 0, 0, -4856, -3308, 4592, 4592,
        2969, 2969, -4851, 201, 47, -1960, -1960, -1960, -1960, 0, -1181,
        -4296, 0, 0, 0, -87, 0, -4796, -1630, -3903, 720, 720, 0, 0, 4341,
        4341, -911, -911, -2980, -2222, -2222, -2222, 0, 0, 0, -1198, 1609,
        2435, 0, 1623, 1623, 0, 1256, -3594, 3234, -316, -2103, 3289, 0,
        3765, 2156, 2156, 2158, 2158, 2158, -1958, -526, -2735, -2735, 98,
        3157, 4056, 3613, -3940, -3940, 1548, 2735, -4805, -475, -4285,
        -4115, 0, -806, 813, -2120, -2120, 2910, -1645, -1645, 926, 926,
        -1873, -1873, 556, 556, -1857, 2339, 0, 4214, 3887, 2540, -4717,
        3958, 3958, 3958, -963, -963, 0, 4882, -4490, -3035, -4224, -263,
        3646, 894, 0, 0, 0, 2349, 2493, -1124, 1358, -4463, 3136, 1304,
        -4621, -4621, -4621, 3845, 3845, -368, -4793, 1983, -1186, -1200,
        4909, 4909, 4909, 3178, -3670, -42, -1968, 3403, 812, -38, -1570,
        -2693, -674, -4884, 2048, 2276, 1820, 1820, 1820, 79, -1316, -834,
        -477, 0, -1873, 3307, 4222, -234, 961, -2372, 4199, 4199, -1714,
        4668, 4668, -1556, -1556, -4089, 4389, 4026, 0, -3158, -1678,
        -1678, -2960, -2960, -2960, -3427, -3427, 4947, 0, 0, -138, -4103,
        -3391, -3391, 0, 0, -3016, -3990, 4396, -1099, 3406, -3632, -2860,
        69, 4315, 4690, -891, -48, 0, 1470, -3638, 0, 4735, 4735, 631, 631,
        -4769, 2231, 2231, 2231, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1903, 0, 0, 0, 2195, 4142,
        -1396, -1756, 2954, -4427, 178, 4857, 4813, 4813, 547, 547, 547,
        2923, -4627, 1836, -3243, -3243, 3002, 3002, 2600, 2600, 2600, 971,
        0, 0, -1, -1, 4351, 4351, 4351, 2351, -2209, -1771, 3061, -3381,
        -3381, -4978, 923, -2470, 512, 512, 2468, 3987, 3987, 3987, 1993,
        -3338, -3338, 0, -1696, 3087, 1165, -4491, -4146, -4146, -2412,
        -4969, 938, 1351, -40, 0, 4035, -3848, 4345, 0, 1176, 2887, 4333,
        4333, 4281, 4281, -354, -354, -371, 4692, 415, -990, -975, 3098,
        3098, 0, 0, 0, 4626, };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger()  = "
            + firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger(first, 0));
}
// returns the first index of the longest repeating sequence of x in input
// for example, if input = {0,0,1,1,1,0,1} and x = 1, then output = 2
public static int firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger(int[] input, int x) { // x = 0
    int firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger = 0; // 74
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        int counter1 = 0;
        if(input[i]== x){
            counter1++;
            firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger = i;
        }

        int counter2= 0;
        if(counter1 > counter2){
            counter1 = firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger;
        }
    }
    return firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger;

}`
```

This is what I have as a way to try to find the index, however this is my result after several attempts since i do not know how to approach this problem. I know that there has to be two counters and when i find that there is a sequence they counter will stop and continue town the array and see if there is a longer repeating sequence. Can anyone lead me in the right direction??? I know the result has to be 74 but i cant reach that conclusion.

Comment: Is this homework? Do you mean "sequence" or "number"?

Comment: I suggest you attempt to debug your program using your debugger, if you do you should notice that you are only looking for sequences of the value `0` because you make `x` equal to 0 and never change it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll typically need two sets of variables when solving problems such as these. Variables to track the max repetitions and start index so far, and likewise, a set to track what you're currently looking at (iterating through).

Move these variables outside of the scope of your loop.

Also, go through each line of your code and comment what each one does.

If you understand your code and how you're trying to solve a problem, then more often than naught, you'll figure out what needs to be fixed.
Your best friend, the [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), says so.